# How can I read an image using cv2.imread after having done the drive.mount from colab?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

After having mounted the drive and having copied and pasted the authentication code I can finally see my files in '/gdrive/My\ Drive/', by selecting an image in here I can actually check that:

```
filePath = '/gdrive/My\ Drive/img.png'
!ls -l $filePath
```

will return the desired file (with 600 permissions for root which I am), so I'm sure that filePath actually refers to the image I want to read. However `os.path.isfile(filePath)` will return `False` and `cv2.imread(filePath)` will return `None`.

Why? Which concept am I actually missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bash command (starting with `!`) then using the backslash to escape the space is correct.

However since you are in python environment when doing `cv2.imread`, you don't need to escape anymore.

Try removing the escaping backslash

```
filePath = '/gdrive/My Drive/img.png'
image = cv2.imread(filePath)
```